# JAVA: Password criteria

Tags: java, passwords

The prompt is:

> Write a Java program to read a string (a password) from the user at the command line and then check that the password conforms to the corporate password policy.
>
> The policy is:
>
> 1) the password must be at least 8 characters
>
> 2) the password must contain one upper case letter
>
> 3) the password must contain one digit.
>
> Use a while loop to step through the string.
>
> Output “Password OK” if the password conforms, otherwise
>
> Output “Password does not conform to the policy.”

I have this down, and it seems to not work still:

```
String password = "";
    boolean hasDigitAndUpper = false;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    int i = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter a password: ");
    password = scnr.nextLine();

    if (Character.isUppercase(password.charAt(i))){
        if (Character.isUppercase(password.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
            hasDigitAndUpper = true;
        }
    }

    while (password.length() < 8 || hasDigitAndUpper != true) {
        System.out.println("Password does not conform to policy");
        System.out.print("Please enter a password: ");
        password = scnr.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Password OK");
```

I guess my biggest issue is my boolean which I can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: Something that pops out: once you get a new password, you don't recompile hasDigitAndUpper. Java will not automatically keep it up to date for you.

Comment: Ahh. I'm fairly new to coding so I didn't know that. Thanks yshavit!

GhostCat: I've been out all day in work and class and is just getting back to this question now. Lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some hints:

```
if (Character.isUppercase(password.charAt(i))){
    if (Character.isUppercase(password.charAt(i))) {
        i++;
        hasDigitAndUpper = true;
    }
}
```

Further down you are using a while-loop. So you have heard of loops before. Hint: you want to for-loop the whole string and check **all** chars. In my passwords, the uppercase characters usually turn up later behind index 0 or 1.

Then:

```
while (password.length() < 8 || hasDigitAndUpper != true) {
    System.out.println("Password does not conform to policy");
    System.out.print("Please enter a password: ");
    password = scnr.nextLine();
}
```

Will not do anything reasonable. You want that loop **around** the other code. This code just loops and asks the user to enter a new password that has 8 chars - that other boolean `hasDigitAndUpper` has its **old** value.

So: you want to write **one** little method **per** criteria; and then your code goes:

```
while (not-all-criteria) {
  password = new user input
  check password length
  check password has upper case 
  ...
```

Hope that is enough to get you going , and please understand that I am not going to do your homework for you. You are in urgent need to practice those things yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function. This iterates over the password and checks the conditions. If all conditions are satisfied then it returns true, Else false.

```
public static boolean isValid(String pwd)
{
    if (pwd == null || pwd.length() < 8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    boolean containUpper = false;
    boolean containDigit = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < pwd.length())
    {
        if (containDigit && containUpper)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (Character.isUpperCase(pwd.charAt(i)))
        {
            containUpper = true;
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(pwd.charAt(i)))
        {
            containDigit = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return containDigit & containUpper;
}
```